# How to make Bootstrap 4 disabled input appear the same as regular inputs?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Normally a disabled input in bootstrap 4 will be greyed-out, to indicate it's disabled status to the user. I want to remove this grey background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that adding the bootstrap `bg-white` class to the input element was enough to override the grey background, thus achieving the look I was after.
Example:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control bg-white" value="Example" disabled />
```